# How to use Mongodb mapReduce for selection?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, nosql, mongodb-query

I have a dataset of students grades. I want to apply map reduce in order to get all the grades of a specific student by his or her ID.

dataset example:

```
{ "StudentID" : 1, "Subject" : "Maths", "Grade": "Good" }
{ "StudentID" : 1, "Subject" : "Physics", "Grade": "Excellent" }
{ "StudentID" : 2, "Subject" : "Maths", "Grade": "Very Good" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can be achieved without using map reduce , simple aggregation framework can be used to accomplish this requirement.

```
    db.student.aggregate([{"$match":{"StudentID":1}},{"$group":{"_id":"$StudentID","grades":{"$push":"$Grade"}}}])
```